# Creación WebService(Rest)

Tags: json, webservice, rest

Estoy usando el programa Talend ESB para la creación de un servicio rest. El trabajo creado funciona perfectamente en "localhost:8088/clientes" donde accediendo por URL puedo ver los datos enviados por rest.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante, cuando quiero acceder desde fuera de la red no me deja (cambiando localhost por la IP PÚBLICA). Me he leído todo el manual y lo he preguntado en el foro de "Talend" pero nadie me responde.

Supongo que en los ficheros de configuración debería configurar un apache o algo por el estilo, no? O puede ser que tenga que abrir los puertos(en este caso el 8088) del PC?

Accepto cualquier sugerencia/idea, Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí intervienen varios factores, entre ellos, el tema de infraestructura de red: Además de acceder por la ip pública deberías redirigir el tráfico de entrada (o por lo menos el del puerto que da servicio) a la máquina que tiene el servicio Rest. Finalmente, tienes que asegurarte que la máquina no tiene ninguna restricción o un firewall que impide que pueda procesar las peticiones.

Comment: También toca asegurarse de que el servidor haga binding a la IP de red local y no solo a la loopback address.